# How to insert data into two tables at once using SQLiteDatabase in Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

So lets say I have this code:

```
SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
long iD = 0;
iD = sqlDB.insert(Table1, null, TestV);
```

Can I somehow rewrite this to insert into two tables instead of one?  My problem is that 'values' returns 3 values from one table, and 1 value from another.  Therefore, the 1 value that isn't in 'Table1' sets off an error that the column cant be found in 'Table1.'  Is there a way to do this?  If not then should I do two separate inserts?  I am confused as how to insert data into two tables in one database (Tables are Relational: one has a foreign key).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) for INSERT in SQLite:

[image]

Note that the flowchart doesn't give you an opportunity to post into more than one table at once. `SQLiteDatabase.insert()` is a convenience method for using the INSERT statement.

Comment: I have seen this diagram before.  I simply curious if there is a way around it, and if not any options.

Answer (score 5):

You can simulate this using database transaction:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();

    try {

        db.execSQL("insert into table1...");
        db.execSQL("insert into table2...");

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

You may need to choose the order of the inserts if there are dependencies between the values inserted, for instance if there's a foreign key relationship: ( insert to table1 and then table2, or first insert to table2...)