# SQL insert query combined with select

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, insert

I want to insert a dataset in a table. The insert query should insert the data into two tables.

Here are the tables:

Table A:

```
ID, customerId, ..[some other columns]...
```

Table B:

```
customerId, name
```

The query should insert into both Table A and Table B. How can I insert values into Table B with the relation `customerId`?

EDIT: the DBMS is sqlite.

The defintions:

Adaption:

- id -> integer not null
- customerId -> integer not null
- some text columns....

Customer:

- customerId -> integer not null
- name -> text not null

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Write two insert statements, one for each table. If one of the tables happens to be the customer table, then this insert must be first.

Comment: Show us the table definitions.

Comment: The DBMS is sqlite.
The defintions:
Adaption: 
id -> integer not null,
customerId -> integer not null,
some text columns; //

Customer:
customerId -> integer not null,
name -> text not null

Comment: [stack overflow, insert data into multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327851/how-to-insert-data-into-two-tables-at-once-using-sqlitedatabase-in-android)
look into the page, i hope this is what you looking for......

Comment: Edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, I fully understand your problem, but i suggest you to see into the technology called :

> Transaction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)

Technically that will be still two (or more) insert queries, but it will let you keep the integrity of your dataset. Transactions are implemented in the most DBMS.